# Posting data on server in android

Tags: android, post

i am trying to post data on server using following code, but the data is posted for one field only other fields are posted null. what is the problem in my code. is there any other changes i need to do in my android app?

```
public void postData(String name,String email,String mobile,String subject,String          message,String url)
{
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

    Log.i("name",name);
    Log.i("email",email);
    Log.i("subject",subject);
    Log.i("mobile",mobile);
    Log.i("url",url);

    try {
        // Add your data
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", subject));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",subject));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", subject));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", subject));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", subject));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: You've had two solid answers from production code, it would be appreciated if you got back to these answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", subject));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",subject));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", subject));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subject", subject));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", subject));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Your code look fine to me. check if `subject` is not null.
Because you have set them all with `subject`!

Comment: Subject is not null. only one values is posted in my code at server, what is the problem?

Comment: Could be a bug in your server then. Can you post the relevant PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that you are absolutely wrong for passing a nameValuePairList, but the object I pass to httpPost.setEntity() is MultipartEntity.

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("KEY", new StringBody("some string"));
reqEntity.addPart("ANOTHER_KEY", new StringBody("another string"));
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity)
```

MultipartEntity is part of Apache Http Components

http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

the http client download has httpmime-4.x.x.jar which contains the class. You only need the httpmime jar, the rest you don't need.

Comment: can not find MultipartEntity in my app.

Comment: You can get HttpClient library with httpmime.jar from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: No need for a third library when you can do it with the available libraries. I dont recommend this one.

Comment: What do you use Lazy ninja for multipart post entries? and technically the HTTPClient is the same library, just that one component from HTTPClient was not included as part of the android sdk for whatever reason, I don't know.

I'm certainly open to a better answer of course, but the above does work and is the way to use multipart form data with HTTPClient.

Comment: For MultipartEntity, I use the library you have mentionned! But in his case he doesnt need it.